# For $A^2 \ne I $ show that $A^k \ne I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a symmetric matrix such that 
$A \in M _n (\mathbb{R})$ and
$$A^2 \ne I\textrm{.}$$
Show that for every $k > 1$, 
$$A^k \ne I\textrm{.}$$

Comment: Perhaps it's over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Its over R, I'v edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need the condition that $A$ is a *real* symmetric matrix.  In this case, $A$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are real, so $A = PDP^{-1}$ for some matrix $P$, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ on its diagonal.  Note that $A^k = PD^k P^{-1}$, and $D^k$ is computed by simply raising each diagonal entry to the $k$th power.

If $A^2 \neq I$, then some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is neither $1$ nor $-1$.  Thus $D^k$ contains a diagonal entry $\lambda^k \neq 1$.  If $PD^kP^{-1}$ were the identity matrix, then $D^k$ would have to be the identity matrix, since the identity map has the same matrix representation with respect to any basis.  Thus $A^k$ cannot be the identity matrix.